# OpenDDS IDL Sequence type

Tags: image, sequence, idl, opendds

I am trying to publish video frames using the following IDL:

```
typedef sequence<octet> Pixels;
module message {
   @topic
   struct Image {
      int width;
      int height;
      int bytesPerPixel;
      Pixels  data;
};
```

I would also like to send 2 image data sequences (say, raw and filtered). Instead of declaring "Pixels data2", can sequence container by declared as arrays? The `typedef sequence<octet> Pixels[2]` gives errors.

Comment: `int` isn't a valid IDL type. The integer types are `short` (16 bits), `long` (32 bits), `long long` (64 bits), and the `unsigned` versions of those three.

Comment: After turning the `int`s into `unsigned short`s and adding a missing brace, the IDL is accepted by the IDL compilers. What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I gave this IDL to `opendds_idl`:

```
typedef sequence<octet> Pixels[2];
module message {
  @topic
  struct Image {
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
    unsigned short bytesPerPixel;
    Pixels data;
  };
};
```

and it accepted it:

```
opendds_idl --syntax-only test.idl                                                    
processing test.idl
```

However I decided to try to build a library with it in case the generated code was wrong, which seems to be true.

```
testTypeSupportImpl.cpp: In function ‘bool OpenDDS::DCPS::gen_skip_over(OpenDDS::DCPS::Serializer&, Pixels_forany*)’:
testTypeSupportImpl.cpp:83:41: error: ‘sequence’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘servent’?
     if (!gen_skip_over(ser, static_cast<sequence*>(0))) return false;
```

With other errors following. It seems we don't support trying to typedef an array and sequence at the same time. Replacing the typedef with two works:

```
typedef sequence<octet> PixelSeq;
typedef PixelSeq Pixels[2];
```

Comment: Reported this upstream, see https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/issues/1931

Comment: Exactly, that is the error I was getting when building library. Thank you, it works now!